# How to change the servletRequest content length in the filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, encryption

I am trying to encrypt the POST body requests going out from my web application to my service.

And the encrypting is done in the filter.

I am facing issues with content length, the content length is set for the post call in `JavaScript` and in the filter as the encrypting is done, the content length changes (the length increases) and when the post data is transferred to the service the data is truncated to the length of the data it has initially (before encryption) which makes the data unusable.

Encryption code:

```
public void jsonEncrypt(String passPhrase, int iterationCount, int keySize, String salt, String initializationVector) throws IOException { 
    String json = new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
    AesUtil aesUtil = new AesUtil(keySize, iterationCount); 

    encryptJsonText = aesUtil.encrypt(salt, initializationVector, passPhrase, json); 
    byte[] b = encryptJsonText.getBytes(); 
    body = b; 
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code used to encrypt and send the data? If you need encryption why don't you rely on `HTTPS`?

Comment: The following is the method I use to encrypt the JSON
I have a requirement that the request should not be in a readable format so that the request data is not manipulated.  

`public void jsonEncrypt(String passPhrase, int iterationCount, int keySize, String salt, String initializationVector) throws IOException 
    {
     String json = new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     AesUtil aesUtil = new AesUtil(keySize, iterationCount);
     encryptJsonText = aesUtil.encrypt(salt, initializationVector, passPhrase, json);
        byte[] b = encryptJsonText.getBytes();
     body = b;
    }`

Comment: I've edited your question adding the code, next time remember you should edit question instead of posting code in a comment.. By the way, this is the server side encryption, right?

Comment: Thanks... Yes.this is server side encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to fix the issue I override the `getContentLength()` method to return the new length.By this I am able to encrypt the request body and send it to my service where I decrypt the body and use it.